# Batch Convert TDM files to XLS

Tags: excel, vba

MY GOAL: Batch convert all .TDM files in a folder to .XLS using an existing add-in by adapting this macro that only works 1 file at a time. (Also open to any VBA approach.)

Using an existing add-in, a single .TDM file is converted into a single .XLS workbook with multiple sheets.

I need to, instead of using a prompt to select a single .TDM file, automatically convert all .TDM files in a folder into new .XLS workbooks.

This is part of a multi-stage process. I tried various loops, mimicking other set-ups, and merging it with other code I found on various community boards.

FYI: .TDM files hold engineering data output produced by testing equipment.

```
Sub GetTDM_AddIn()

'Get TDM Excel Add-In
 Dim obj As COMAddIn
 Set obj = Application.COMAddIns.Item("ExcelTDM.TDMAddin")
 'obj.Connect = True

 'Confirm only importing "Description" properties for Root
 Call obj.Object.Config.RootProperties.DeselectAll
 Call obj.Object.Config.RootProperties.Select("Description")

 'Show the group count as property
 Call obj.Object.Config.RootProperties.Select("Groups")

 'Select all the available properties for Group
 Call obj.Object.Config.GroupProperties.SelectAll

 'Import custom properties
 obj.Object.Config.RootProperties.SelectCustomProperties = True
 obj.Object.Config.GroupProperties.SelectCustomProperties = True
 obj.Object.Config.ChannelProperties.SelectCustomProperties = True

 'Let the user choose which file to import
 Dim fileName
 fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("TDM & TDMS (*.tdm;*.tdms),*.tdm;*.tdms")
 If fileName = False Then
 ' User selected Cancel
 Exit Sub
 End If

 'Import the selected file
 Call obj.Object.ImportFile(fileName)

 'Record down the current workbook
 Dim Workbook As Object
 Set Workbook = ActiveWorkbook

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an Excel Macro (VBA Script) I wrote to do something very similar to what you want to do.  It converts a directory of .tdms files to their equivalent .csv files.  It requires the ExcelTDM Add In (NITDMEXCEL_2015-0-0.exe) which I obtained at http://www.ni.com/example/27944/en/.  I tested the script in Excel 2013 running on a modest Windows 7 Pro machine converting 24 TDMS files with 120,000 rows each file.  It completed the conversions without error in about 2 minutes 30 seconds which is about 7 seconds per file.  Please forgive my hasty error handling and poor VBA form.

```
Sub ConvertTDMStoCSV()
'
' ConvertTDMS Macro
'
' Acts upon all .tdms files in a "source" directory,
' loading each one using the ExcelTDM Add In,
' deleting the first sheet and saving the
' remaining stream data as one .csv file
' in a "target" directory.  Writes a list of
' the files converted in a new sheet.
'
' Tested to work with Excel 2013 on Windows 7
' with NITDMEXCEL_2015-0-0.exe obtained at
' http://www.ni.com/example/27944/en/

    Dim sourceDir As String, targetDir As String, fn As String, fnBase As String
    Dim fso As Object, n As Long, resp As Integer, strNow As String, newSheet As Object
    Dim tdmsAddIn As COMAddIn, importedWorkbook As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set tdmsAddIn = Application.COMAddIns.Item("ExcelTDM.TDMAddin")
    tdmsAddIn.Connect = True
    Call tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.RootProperties.DeselectAll
    Call tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.ChannelProperties.DeselectAll
    tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.RootProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False
    tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.GroupProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False
    tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.ChannelProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False


    'Choose TDMS Source Directory
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Choose Source Directory of TDMS Files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        sourceDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    If Dir(sourceDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No such folder.", vbCritical, sourceDir
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Choose CSV Target Directory
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Choose Target Directory for CSV Files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        targetDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    If Dir(targetDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No such folder.", vbCritical, targetDir
        Exit Sub
    End If



    fn = Dir(sourceDir & "\*.tdms")
    If fn = "" Then
        MsgBox "No source TDMS files found.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    resp = MsgBox("Begin conversion of TDMS files?" & vbCrLf & sourceDir & vbCrLf & "to" & vbCrLf & targetDir, vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
    If resp = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Execution cancelled by user."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    strNow = WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "m-d-yyyy h_mm_ss")
    newSheet.Name = strNow
    newSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Files converted on " & strNow
    newSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "TDMS Source Directory: " & sourceDir
    newSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = "CSV Target Directory: " & targetDir


    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    n = 5
    Do While fn <> ""
        fnBase = fso.GetBaseName(fn)

        On Error Resume Next
        Call tdmsAddIn.Object.ImportFile(sourceDir & "\" & fn, True)
        If Err Then
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set importedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        importedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
        importedWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetDir & "\" & fnBase & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        importedWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        newSheet.Cells(n, 1).Value = fnBase
        n = n + 1
        fn = Dir
    Loop
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    Set fso = Nothing
    Set newSheet = Nothing
    Set importedWorkbook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do this in VBA, I suggest that you use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to get all of the files and then call the Excel macro, for each file, using the `Run` method.

You'll also need to modify the macro to either (1) run on the current open file (solution below); or (2) take a filename as an argument (this changes the call to `Run` below)

The code is something like this (modify the call to `get-childitem` to fit your applicaton):

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$files = get-childitem ... #etc, collect your files into an array
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $wb = $excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname)
    $ws= $wb.worksheets.item(1)
    $ws.Activate()
    $excel.Run("GetTDM_AddIn")
    $wb.save()
    $wb.close()
}
$excel.quit()
```

Comment: David, thank you for your response. I am an accounting person, not an IT system administrator. I am not familiar with powershell.

Comment: @Mario Ok - that's fine.  However, you might want to edit your question and remove the following statement "Also open to any new approach".

Comment: David, I will certainly explore the powershell option, so your answer is valuable. I Googled it and am very interested.  I'm sorry, by another option, I meant another VBA approach or conversion method.  I will edit it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple app to convert tdms files.
It supports multiple files and has command line support.
http://www.whiterocksoftware.com/2019/11/batch-convert-tdms-to-excel.html