# Importing Multiple TDM files through TDMExcelAddIn gives error in 'Import File' method

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins

I want to modify the normal functionality provided by the TDMExcelAddIn from importing one file at a time to importing multiple files together.

I came across this thread which was similar: [Batch Convert TDM files to XLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369786/batch-convert-tdm-files-to-xls)

I decided to use the code @James Humphrey presented here.
I modified the code to include '.tdm' file istead of '.tdms'
However, after providing the required directories, the conversion doesn't happen and I get the error:

> "The Method 'Import File' for the Object 'TDMAddIn' has failed'

The modified code:

```
Sub ConvertTDMStoCSV()
'
' ConvertTDMS Macro
'
' Acts upon all .tdms files in a "source" directory,
' loading each one using the ExcelTDM Add In,
' deleting the first sheet and saving the
' remaining stream data as one .csv file
' in a "target" directory.  Writes a list of
' the files converted in a new sheet.
'
' Tested to work with Excel 2013 on Windows 7
' with NITDMEXCEL_2015-0-0.exe obtained at
' http://www.ni.com/example/27944/en/

    Dim sourceDir As String, targetDir As String, fn As String, fnBase As String
    Dim fso As Object, n As Long, resp As Integer, strNow As String, newSheet As Object
    Dim tdmsAddIn As COMAddIn, importedWorkbook As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set tdmsAddIn = Application.COMAddIns.Item("ExcelTDM.TDMAddin")
    'tdmsAddIn.Connect = True
    Call tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.RootProperties.DeselectAll
    Call tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.ChannelProperties.DeselectAll
    tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.RootProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False
    tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.GroupProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False
    tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.ChannelProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False

    'Choose TDMS Source Directory
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Choose Source Directory of TDMS Files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        sourceDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    If Dir(sourceDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No such folder.", vbCritical, sourceDir
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Choose CSV Target Directory
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Choose Target Directory for CSV Files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        targetDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    If Dir(targetDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No such folder.", vbCritical, targetDir
        Exit Sub
    End If

    fn = Dir(sourceDir & "\*.tdm")
    If fn = "" Then
        MsgBox "No source TDMS files found.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    resp = MsgBox("Begin conversion of TDMS files?" & vbCrLf & sourceDir & vbCrLf & "to" & vbCrLf & targetDir, vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
    If resp = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Execution cancelled by user."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    strNow = WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "m-d-yyyy h_mm_ss")
    newSheet.Name = strNow
    newSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Files converted on " & strNow
    newSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "TDMS Source Directory: " & sourceDir
    newSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = "CSV Target Directory: " & targetDir

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    n = 5
    Do While fn <> ""
        fnBase = fso.GetBaseName(fn)

        On Error Resume Next
        Call tdmsAddIn.Object.ImportFile(sourceDir & "\" & fn, True)
        If Err Then
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set importedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        importedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
        importedWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=targetDir & "\" & fnBase & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        importedWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        newSheet.Cells(n, 1).Value = fnBase
        n = n + 1
        fn = Dir
    Loop
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set newSheet = Nothing
    Set importedWorkbook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to convert tdms to excel  :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgHD3ztpLes

it was a little slow with my file but as result I've got excel file with all data.